# Return index path when clicking a text field

Tags: ios

What I am trying to accomplish is somehow get the indexpath of the cell, when the app user clicks a UITextfield to edit the text. I thought/tried to use gestures to do this but couldn't see how to do it. Any help would be greatly appreciated. 
Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use uitextfield delegate method to get the cell of uitableview

```
- (void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField
```

Then, access the cell by accessing the parent/superview of textfield

```
UIView *cellView = (UIVIew *)[textfield superview];
UITableViewCell *cell = (UITableViewCell *)[cellView superview];
NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableview indexPathForCell:cell];
```

Hope, this will solve your problem.